# Honeywell programmable switch: lights always on...?

Tags: lighting, smart-switch

I have a Honeywell [programmable switch](https://www.honeywellstore.com/store/products/honeywell-econoswitch-7-day-solar-programmable-light-switch-timer-white.htm) for outdoor lights. Recently, I realized that even when the switch is supposed to be off (during the day), the lightbulbs are not completely turned off. They are much less bright than during the night but there is still a noticeable light... Thus, I am assuming something is wrong with my switch... Has anyone encountered this issue ? Is there any way to reset the switch ?

Comment: What make/model/type of lightbulbs are these?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel, I tried two types of Uberhaus LED lights (2700K) similar to these ones: https://www.amazon.ca/UBERHAUS-2700K-White-Equivalent-Dimmable/dp/B07NRTVL3Z]

Comment: This is a common problem with dimmers, lighted switches, motion detectors, and dusk-to-dawn sensors that don't need a neutral. It's the over-covered LED bulb parasitic power problem. Try better LED bulbs, replacing the switch, or using tungsten bulbs.

Comment: Can you post photos of the inside of the junction box for the switch please?